# Cannot read AWS credentials using .NET Core SDK on Centos 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-webapi, centos7, aws-cli

I've installed AWS CLI on my Centos 7 server. In my .NET Core Web API project, I initialize an `AmazonS3Client` to upload files to my S3 bucket: `_client = new AmazonS3Client();`

However, the API seems to have a problem in getting the credentials and config located in `/.aws` directory. I've tried running the `aws configure` command to configure AWS credentials, but the API keeps throwing an exception with message `Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service`. When installing AWS CLI on my local Windows PC, the API can get the credentials and the config without any errors and runs fine.

My Centos 7 server has multiple .NET Core projects running. Is that a cause of this problem?

Comment: If you are using instance, you should be providing aws permissions through instance role. This is what your project expects, and it it fails to find it.

Comment: @Marcin I'm not using an EC2 instance, just a private centos server